# Modal not working in Reactjs-bootstrap app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to get a modal to popup when Login is clicked but nothing populates.

Im using the 'react-bootstrap' library.

Here is the code:

```
var React  = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap');

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div className='static-modal'>
        <Modal title='Modal title'
          enforceFocus={false}
          backdrop={false}
          animation={false}
          container={mountNode}
          onRequestHide={function() {}}>
          <div className='modal-body'>
            One fine body...
          </div>
          <div className='modal-footer'>
            <Button>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle='primary'>Save changes</Button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


module.exports = Login;
```

Any idea why it's not rendering?
FYI, I am also using react router to route thru the components.

Comment: The code likely throws a reference error because the variable `mountNode` is not defined.

Comment: Good catch -- but what would be passed in to container for for the modal to populate?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` in the container props. It will mount your modal
`container={this}`